error during build in Vercel, Rollup failed to resolve
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-router-dom" from "/vercel/path0/src/main.jsx".

everything that i have in main.jsx:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-tailwind/react";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ThemeProvider>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Github link: https://github.com/yusufyildirimYY/VoltVitrin
Website working without a problem but i'm getting the error above when i try deploying with vercel
